# Plotting a table with many y values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm trying to plot a bifurcation map for a Lorenz System. I have a function (called `estables` in the code that follows) which, for a certain value r, returns the list of stationary points for the system with that parameter r.

Then I do this:

```
r0 = 0;
rf = 10;
dr = 0.5;
ys = Table[estables[ra], {ra, r0, rf, dr}]

ListPlot[ Flatten[ys, {2}], PlotRange -> All , DataRange -> {r0, rf}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Small]}, Joined -> False ]
```

And I get a weird thing where the points  are plotted out of order. That is, the points in the first line are not the ones plotted above the 0, as it should be.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Edit: This are the differential equations:

```
ecf = σ (p[t] - f[t]);
ecp = -p[t] + d[t] f[t];
ecd = b (r - d[t] - f[t] p[t]);
```

and this is the function

```
t0 = 100;
tf = 105;
dt = 0.05;

estables[ra_] :=

Module[{par, solnum, fs}, 
    par = {σ -> 3., b -> 1, r -> ra}; 
    solnum = 
      NDSolve[{Derivative[1][f][t] == ecf, 
               Derivative[1][p][t] == ecp, 
               Derivative[1][d][t] == ecd, 
               f[0] == 0.00001, p[0] == 0., 
               d[0] == 1} /. par, 
               {f, p, d}, {t, t0, tf}, 
               MaxSteps -> 100000
    ];
    fs = Flatten[Table[Evaluate[f[t] /. solnum], {t, t0, tf, dt}]]; 
    Union[FindPeaks[fs], -FindPeaks[-fs]]][[;; , 2]]
```

Comment: Including the definition of `estables` would certainly help us to help you.

Comment: I didn't include it for brevity, but yes, you're probably right.

Comment: Where are `t0`, `tf`, and `dt`?

Comment: I have a suggestion: why not use `WhenEvent[]` instead to capture the points where `f'[t] == 0`?

Comment: Mmm, I suspected there would be a more sophisticated way to capture the stable points, that looks good. I'm not sure how to use it, though. Which action should be triggered when `f'[t] ==0`?

Comment: Look at the docs for `WhenEvent[]`; pay attention to the examples using `Sow[]`/`Reap[]`.

Comment: Brilliant! That's way more elegant, thanks. I get a couple of spurious maximums, however. If I plot that interval I see very clearly that f[t] oscillates between 18 and -15, but I get a maximum with f = 25, for some reason. I guess its just the numerical solver doing weird things at the beginning of the interval, but it really troubles me.

Comment: Fixed! My problem was that I was not properly dropping the transient of each system. Setting the limits of NDSolve to be `t0` and `tf` wasn't enough, I had to change the condition in `WhenEvent []` to `f'[t] == 0 && t > t0 `. Thank you very much for your help, J.M.

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, consider posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: I see a mod edited my code here (thanks, it reads better now) and, amongst other things, changed the derivatives from `f'[t]` notation to `Derivative[1][f][t]`. Why is that? Is it considered bad style to use the first one?

Comment: Either of `f'[t]` or `Derivative[1][f][t]` is acceptable. In any case, none of the editors made the change; [you yourself put it there](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/115654/revisions) (see revision 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to J.M. I found a more elegant way to obtain the statinoary values that returned far simpler data, which was easy to plot. This is how my code looks now:

```
ecf = s (p[t] - f[t]);
ecp = -p[t] + d[t] f[t];
ecd = b (r - d[t] - f[t] p[t]);

par = {s -> 3., b -> 1, r -> 100};
t0 = 800;
tf = 850;



estables[ra_] :=

 Module[{par, solnum,  points}, 
  par = {s -> 3., b -> 1, r -> ra}; 
  {solnum, points} = Reap@NDSolve[{
           Derivative[1][f][t] == ecf, 
           Derivative[1][p][t] == ecp, 
           Derivative[1][d][t] == ecd, 
           f[0] == 0.00001, p[0] == 0., 
           d[0] == 1, 
           WhenEvent[{f'[t] == 0 && t > t0}, Sow[f[t]]]} 
           /. par, {f, p, d}, {t, t0, tf}, MaxSteps -> 100000];
  Flatten[points]
];


r0 = 0;
rf = 105;
dr = 0.2;

ys = Table[{ra, e}, {ra, r0, rf, dr}, {e, estables[ra]}];
ListPlot[ Flatten[ys, 1], PlotRange -> All , DataRange -> {r0, rf}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.002]}, Joined -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {r, f} ]
```

Comment: Great job on self answer! When I copy and run your code it appears that points 2 and 3 generate an error. The rest of the points appear to be OK.

Comment: Actually, I've just found out that my code is wrong. It gives a close enough diagram, but a lot of "spurious" points appear that shouldn't be there. Is that what you mean? I've almost managed to fix it, I will edit in a moment.